# Force merge after reverting merge commit int git

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I've merged a branch to master, than reverted merge commit. Now I want to merge the branch again, but merge says that everything is up to date. I understand why -- the branch is already in master's history.

Is there any way to "force" merge in that case or I should just revert the revert of the merge?

Comment: check out this page for unscrewing-up your git mistakes: http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to force a merge; indeed, reverting the revert is the correct way to do it (see https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt where Linus discusses this). Note that if there are commits on the branch *after* the (reverted) merge that you want in master, you will need to of course merge in the branch as well.